# CSS Add offset / distort between multiple borders?

Tags: css

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hermann-pcpcsy?file=/src/styles.module.css

I want to create multi sector element using css. I need 4 segments as shown below:

```
<div className={classes.loader}>
                <section className={classes.loader_sector}></section>
                <section className={classes.loader_sector}></section>
                <section className={classes.loader_sector}></section>
                <section className={classes.loader_sector}></section>
            </div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.loader_sector {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.8rem solid transparent;
}

.loader_sector:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(3) {
  border-right-color: #fff;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

but this keeps all this circles stick together:

[image]
I want some gap at junction of every sector. Can someone help me achieve the same?

Edit one:

As suggested in comments using margin-top left and right solves the problem, but the core issue still remains, when I rotate them, they start contracting: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hermann-pcpcsy?file=/src/styles.module.css

Comment: Can you post a working example using stackSnippet?

Comment: Hey I have added sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hermann-pcpcsy?file=/src/styles.module.css

I want border length to be slightly less so that I could have gaps around these rings

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-microservice-iwhv3k?file=/src/styles.module.css

Comment: Hey thanks, though this distorts them when rotating: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hermann-pcpcsy?file=/src/styles.module.css
Can you help me with that too please? Ideally these sectors were supposed to rotate uniformly with those gaps

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-water-07dl7n?file=/src/styles.module.css Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you can play with border radius and gap between sections to make it pretty.

```css
.Spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loader > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loader {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  animation: rotate 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.loader_sector {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.8rem solid transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;

  pointer-events: none;
}

.loader_sector:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-color: pink;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-color: blue;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(3) {
  border-right-color: green;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=Spinner>
      <div class=loader>
        <section class=loader_sector></section>
        <section class=loader_sector></section>
        <section class=loader_sector></section>
        <section class=loader_sector></section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this css code in your css file, it will work.

```
.Spinner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: black;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.loader > * {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loader {
/* background-color: white; */
position: relative;
height: 10rem;
width: 10rem;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.loader_sector {
position: absolute;
/* background-color: blue; */
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 0.8rem solid transparent;
}

.loader_sector:nth-child(1) {
 border-top-color: pink;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(2) {
 border-left-color: blue;
 margin-left: -10px;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(3) {
 border-right-color: green;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.loader_sector:nth-child(4) {
 border-bottom-color: yellow;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see... thanks a lot but one more quick thing I need to understand, actually I want to rotate this whole sectors they come close: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hermann-pcpcsy?file=/src/styles.module.css

Can you please suggest a fix for that too?

Comment: Thanks,I will try, please accept my answer if you find it correct.